# How could I remove text inside quotes in atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I came from vim. Its biggest win is commands like `ci<` when `<this text is removed if cursor is placed inside angle brackets>`

How can I do that in hackable editor for the XXI century?

Comment: Did you try using `ctrl+shift+space`? This does select the brackets as well, though.

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [vim-mode-plus](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus) plugin. It natively supports your example, and many other text-object style commands taken straight from Vim, e.g. all of these would work as well:

- `di<`
- `da<`
- `ca<`

And it should work with `'`, `"`, `(`, and other delimiters, just like Vim.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that comes with the editor named `bracket-matcher:select-inside-brackets` that highlight everything inside the bracket (but not the bracket itself). You may then press backspace or delete button to remove the content, or any other button to replace the content. For windows, the default key combination is `ctrl-alt-m`.

If you are not using windows, or you may have accidentally overwritten the settings, you may open Setting > Keybindings and search `bracket-matcher:select-inside-brackets`. It should tell you what is the correct key combination.